# python web request scraping return error 404

Tags: python, python-requests-html

iam trying to web **scrape** this yellow page website to get contacts detail below iam trying to do a POST requests but return with a 404 error message. iam using https://curl.trillworks.com/ to convert my response to python.

```
import requests

headers = {
   'authority': 'www.google-analytics.com',
   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
   'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^Chromium^\\^;v=^\\^94^\\^, ^\\^Google',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '^\\^Windows^\\^',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
'origin': 'https://www.yellowpages.vu',
'content-type': 'text/plain',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36',
'accept': '*/*',
'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'referer': 'https://www.yellowpages.vu/search/results',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8',
'cookie': 'c48afa9a35ba10b75b2d5013ea9c8a8e=5c508b71eea0e6b13c24cb2d048b2fff; 
SPro_ssid=163282557391.71.0; _ga=GA1.2.1650230856.1632825595; 
_gid=GA1.2.1275902665.1632825595; _gat=1',
'Referer': 'https://www.yellowpages.vu/templates/yellowpages/XTC/css.php? 
id=15&groups=typo,grid,style1,css3effects',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
 Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36',
'Origin': 'https://www.yellowpages.vu',
'content-length': '0',
}

params = (
   ('reset', '1'),
)

data = {
'xt_search_for': 'car',
'to_sid_list_1': '',
'field_city': '',
'ssid': '163282557391.71.0',
'sid': '1',
'task': 'search.search',
'option': 'com_sobipro',
'Itemid': '187',
'6f7efb93929c56901a56bdeab2f7e50c': '1',
'sectionid': '1',
'default_query': '',
'field_categories': '',
'sp_search_for': 'car'
}

response = requests.post('https://www.yellowpages.vu/search/index.php', 
headers=headers, params=params, data=data)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your headers, you have the following line:

```
'content-type': 'text/plain',
```

This is tripping off the website, as the actual content type should be:

```
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
```

---

Update: Regarding your follow up question, I couldn't entirely pinpoint why the site was bugging out to different requests, but I figured out that by removing the headers entirely, the code works. It's important to point out that just like @C.Nivs mentioned, you don't actually need to specify the headers, as the headers are usually supplemented by the module.

After these fixes, the code should work properly:

```py
import requests

data = {
    "xt_search_for": "car",
    "to_sid_list_1": "",
    "field_city": "",
    "ssid": "163282557391.71.0",
    "sid": "1",
    "task": "search.search",
    "option": "com_sobipro",
    "Itemid": "187",
    "6f7efb93929c56901a56bdeab2f7e50c": "1",
    "sectionid": "1",
    "default_query": "",
    "field_categories": "",
    "sp_search_for": "car",
}

response = requests.post(
    "https://www.yellowpages.vu/search/index.php",
    data=data
)

print(response.status_code) # 200 OK
print(response.text) # Cars in the results page
```

Comment: thankyou @Xiddoc got <Response [200]>
 success but i should get some results as my search there is 'car' in html format by `print(response.text)`

Comment: I have updated my answer. If it helped you, please upvote it and click on the checkmark to mark it as valid :)

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to specify `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` headers for the most part as these will be handled for you, especially when using the `data` and `json` kwargs:

```py
from requests import Request

r = Request(
    'POST',
    'https://yellowpages.com'
    headers={'authority': 'www.google-analytics.com'}
    params=(('reset', '1'),),
    data={'sid': '1'}
)

req = r.prepare()
req.headers
{'authority': 'www.google-analytics.com', 'Content-Length': '5', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```

This is done behind the scenes when doing `requests.<http_verb>`